# Is or was there a proposal for c++ to use the context for short enum values?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, c++20

I use `enum class` everywhere in our code. Sometimes, the namespaces pile up, making the code less readable as it could be:

```
_infoSign->setType(ui::InfoSign::Type::Ok);
```

I am aware, I could shorten this with a `using` statement:

```
using Type = ui::InfoSign::Type;
_infoSign->setType(Type::Ok);
```

The downside of the `using` statement is the own definition of `Type`. In case the `enum` name is changed to `Foo`, this code will keep the `Type` name and has to be manually updated.

Swift uses an interesting way to handle enum values:

```swift
enum CompassPoint {
    case north
    case south
    case east
    case west
}

func foo(dir: CompassPoint) {
    // ...
}
```

For a function call, the compiler will automatically use the right context and allow a very short form to specify the enum value:

```
foo(.north)
```

**Is or was there a proposal for C++ for a similar syntax?**

Comment: My preferred solution is to not build namespace piles.

Comment: I don't think a proposal exists, nor the idea is feasible for C++: in C++ the functions found by name lookup may depend the arguments, it's too tricky making the latter also depend on the former.

Comment: You didn't ask for a workaround, and you didn't specify why you use enum classes religiously, but if you give up on it for class members, you can already have shorter notation and type safety. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18cef519078ecbe

Comment: Specifically, C++ uses the types of the *arguments* to a function to locate the function's namespace, if it's defined there. Exactly the other way around.

Comment: @cppleaner Yet we have `foo({42})` and `foo({.a = 42})` that can both compile today.

Comment: I don't think `InfoSign::Type` becomes `InfoSign::Foo` produce any problem. At least if this really happens, I would more concern about the inconsistency for this interface, not the inconsistency of my alias name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no similar proposal for precisely that case that I am aware of. That is, to reduce the noise in *initializing* scoped enumerators. It seems similar in style to designated initializers (new for C++20), but kind of against the idea of scoped enumerators being... you know, scoped.

---

The far more common issue about enum classes is the verbosity in switch statements. For *that* problem, there is [P1099: Using Enum](https://wg21.link/p1099), which reduces

```
std::string_view to_string(rgba_color_channel channel) {
  switch (channel) {
    case rgba_color_channel::red:   return "red";
    case rgba_color_channel::green: return "green";
    case rgba_color_channel::blue:  return "blue";
    case rgba_color_channel::alpha: return "alpha";
  }
}
```

to

```
std::string_view to_string(rgba_color_channel channel) {
  switch (my_channel) {
    using enum rgba_color_channel;
    case red:   return "red";
    case green: return "green";
    case blue:  return "blue";
    case alpha: return "alpha";
  }
}
```

I suppose you could also write:

```
using enum ui::InfoSign::Type;
_InfoSign->SetType(Ok);
```

But that's not really any less verbose (unless you do that operation multiple times in the same scope).

Comment: A new proposal would most likely need to address the way how the compiler searches the namespaces. Using the namespace of the argument or lvalue type would be an elegant solution. In the end, the types have to be compatible - therefore a wrong resolution of the value is possible but very unlikely.